# Start service successfully but wait for internet connection

Tags: c#, asynchronous, service, webclient

I'm fairly new to c# and am in the process of writing a system service. One of the first things that the service needs to do is connect to the internet and download a new settings file. However, as there is no guarantee that the machine it is running on will have an internet connection at startup, the service needs to intermittently attempt to download the file.

The problem I'm having is that by sitting in a loop attempting to download the file the service times out (fails to start).

How can I create a loop that will poll my server intermittently while still allowing the service startup to complete?

UPDATE

I have put together the following code. It appears to work in a non-blocking way, but I cannot work out how to stop the timer from within the netCheck function?

```
public static void Start()
{

    // Start the system timer update
    System.Timers.Timer time = new System.Timers.Timer();
    time.Interval = 5*1000; // 3hrs
    time.Elapsed +=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(netCheck);
    time.Start();



}

public static void netCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string download = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.domain.com/ping.php");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(download))
        {
            //stop the clock
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Net...");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No Net...");
    }
}
```

Comment: When does the service time out exactly? When you're starting a service you should not wait in the OnStart method, but start a new Thread if you want to do some "longer work"..

Comment: Like Patrick said, you should not do any processing in the OnStart() method (I assume that's what you mean by Start()) that takes any significant time. The OnStart() method is intended to start one or more new threads that does the service's work, and then return immediately. You should take a look at some tutorials about how a Windows service must work - they are rather different from most programs.

Comment: Another point - testing a Windows service is a pain, but there are tricks that can be used so you test it mostly as a console program, and then when it's working you can install it as a Windows service and make final tests. Here's one example of how to do that: http://einaregilsson.com/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/

Answer (score 0):

You can just set your service's startup type to Automatic (Delayed Start), as shown below. This will allow your network connection to be running and in place before your service starts.

Or, if it's still possible that you won't have an internet connection, even after a delayed start, have your service start a timer and check for an internet connection in your timer callback.

From https://superuser.com/a/285655:

> A service marked as Automatic (Delayed Start) will start shortly after
>   all other services designated as Automatic have been started.

[image]

Comment: My concern is more for laptops (or dsl modems) that may not have a connection available until the user initiates it.

Comment: I just added a comment at the bottom of my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does, I'm trying to work with timers at the moment as I thought that might be the key. I'm having trouble working out how to stop a timer from another function tho. I've updated my original message to show

Comment: It's because you're defining the timer within the start method. Define it at the class level, then your netCheck() method will have access to it. (Actually, both methods will have access to it.)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Just set Enable to false

```
time.Enable=false;
```